# Saving a contact shared via text message

Tags: contacts, 4.4-kitkat

How do I save a contact that was shared with me in a text message?  I have the Droid Maxx, Android version 4.4.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to long-press the number (underlined).

Comment: Thanks, but the message sent to me was a V card that just showed up as the blank square with the small gray square inside that contains a generic image of a person (what you see in the stock text msging program). Sorry I don't know the proper terms. When I long press on that square in the text I received, I get the option to Forward, Lock, View Details, or Delete. No option to save the contact. But based on your answer, I tried a short tap and that gave me the option to save the contact using Backup Assistant or Google contacts. It worked! Thanks for putting me on the right path!

Comment: :)  happy to be helpful